# Why has the statement "printfn" in F# different name in VS2010 object browser?

Tags: f#, function-call

I had know the difference between F# library and .NET library when I called their functions. 
But when I saw the statement "printfn" in VS 2010 object browser, I saw only the "public static T PrintFormatLine(... format)" instead of "printfn".

Why has the statement "printfn" in F# library different name in VS2010 object browser?

How can I call functions in F# library, if there aren’t documents for the F# library, because the names in VS 2010 object browser are totally different?

Comment: Note that there are docs, see e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560.aspx

Comment: Also note that you're not really expected to ever call functions in the F# library from C#. They use various F#-specific types that are difficult to use from C# (in particular, calling `printfn` from C# is probably almost impossible anyway!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `printfn` function in the F# core library is annotated with a special attribute `CompiledName` that specifies the name of the function in a compiled form:

```
[<CompiledName("PrintFormatLine")>]
let printfn fp = ...
```

What is this good for? I think the motivation is that the `FSharp.Core.dll` library should follow the usual .NET naming guidelines. However, F# naming guidelines are a bit different (lowercase names are allowed, etc.), so the attribute is used to make the library look more like ordinary .NET library.

I don't think this is something that users of F# would use themselves. If you're writing code that will be used from C#, write it in a C# friendly style and if you're writing code that will be used from F#, follow the F# naming guidelines.

Comment: And this means that the .Net view shows .Net-conventional names (PascalCase) rather than F# conventional names for module members (camelCase and sometimes abbreviated).  It is rare to call members of FSharp.Core from other languages, though.

Comment: The F# docs are right here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233154(VS.100).aspx

Comment: @dagelee the source code is also available.  https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/printf.fs#LC606

Comment: Thanks @TomasPetricek. I know the statement "printfn" in F# library wrapped the statement "PrintFormatLine" in .NET library. My question is: if there aren’t documents for the F# library, How can I know the function name "printfn"?

Comment: @dagelee : The documentation does call it `printfn`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370571.aspx